# How I can move the clock to the middle of the menu bar?

Tags: macos, clock

How I can move the clock, by default at the far right side of the menu bar, to the middle of the menu bar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, the answer is: you can't. The way the Mac OS X Menu Bar is set up, Application Menus get added starting in the left hand corner (after the Apple menu) and going right; System and 3rd party Menu Extras get added from the right hand corner and go left. There's no way to absolutely position a menu on the menu bar; you can only change the order of the items.

As Tony mentioned in his answer, the user can reorder [Menu Extras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_extra) by dragging them while holding <kbd>Command</kbd>. Only the developer of an app can reorder the Application's menus. But there's no way to position anything in the center.

Comment: Really is no way? Even non trivial?

Comment: There really is no way to position a Menu Extra in the middle of the menu bar. It is possible you might find a third party clock application which you can get to display the time there, but it won't be a Menu Extra. There's no way to position Menu Extras (Like the built in clock which displays in the menu bar) in the middle.

Comment: Although this is a 7 year old comment, I found that pressing command + dragging anything left and right now works for everything. simple and usefull

Answer (score 6):

Use: https://www.mowglii.com/itsycal/
Add the icon to menu
Move it to the far left using command click
Then in preferences add as many spaces as needed to center the time you want displayed

[image]
See the code below

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZZZ
```

Answer (score 3):

Holding <kbd>Command</kbd> and clicking, and then dragging should do it.

Comment: Doesn't really put in center.